# Show Print activity button for print using SFSafariviewController

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller, uiactivity

In sfsafariviewcontroller screen, share button is only showing default activity options that doesn't have print option, but i want to show only print activity option.

there is delegate method to return activity. i want to return UIPrintActivity option.

func safariViewController(controller: SFSafariViewController, activityItemsForURL URL: NSURL, title: String?) -> [UIActivity]